# Issue with Display:table-cell & Vertical-align:middle not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

This is a simple issue, and i'm sure i am just overlooking something but if you will notice, in the **4th row**, the **label** isn't **aligning vertically**. Take a look at it here on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uidezigns/HJEca/

**HTML**

```
<form class="lable_left">
   <p>
      <label for="fn">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="fn">
   </p>
   <p>
      <label for="ln">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="ln">
   </p>
   <p>
      <label for="ph">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="ph">
   </p>
   <p>
      <label for="ad">Street Address:</label>
      <textarea name="ad"></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
      <label for="ct">City:</label>
      <input type="text" name="ct">
   </p>
   <p>
      <label for="st">State:</label>
      <input type="text" name="st">
   </p>
   <p>
      <label for="zc">Postal:</label>
      <input type="text" name="zc">
   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/* --- skins for visibility - Remove for implementation --- */

form {
    margin: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FAE2BF;
}

form p {
    background-color: #F7CBC7;
}

form label {
    background-color: #E5E2DB;
}

        /*----------------------------------------------------------*/

form {
    font: normal 12px Arial;
    display: block;
}

form p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

form.two_row p {
    width: 50%;
}

form.three_row p {
    width: 33%;
}

form label,form input,form textarea {
    display: block;
}

label {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
}

input {
}

textarea {
    width: 100px height:100px;
    margin: 0;
}

form.lable_left p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form.lable_left label,form.lable_left input,form.lable_left textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

form.lable_left label {
    width: 120px;
}

form.lable_left input {
}

input[type="submit"] {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Include `label { vertical-align: top; }`

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJEca/1/).

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem, see above that i wanted the label to be vertically aligned in the center or middle.

Note: Please no shortcuts using padding and margins.

Comment: guess i fixed it myself...lol

i needed to add:

`form label,form input,form textarea { vertical-align:middle }`

Answer (score 0):

guess i fixed it myself...lol i needed to add:

`form label,form input,form textarea { vertical-align:middle }`

to the css